# Pygal Displays Box plot wrong

Tags: pygal

When displaying a box graph, pygal displays values outside of the normal zones. You can see the example on their site as well:

[image: Box plot from pygal.org]

You'll notice that no values are above 16,000 or below -4000 (in fact none are below 0). It just doesn't display properly.

This is posted for anyone who doesn't look on the website for answers (which I don't usually).

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to this problem, and it is not resolved completely yet - but there is a quick fix.
In the meantime, to make it work (as expected) instantiate the object like this:

```
box_plot = pygal.Box(mode='extremes')
```

You'll notice that the above example will be solved, and in fact to my knowledge this is the only way to make box plots work.

To follow the issue: [Link to the issue request](https://github.com/Kozea/pygal/issues/149)